# how to get the value from dropdownlist in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdownlist in my web-page how i can get the value from the selected option of them

like

```
<select id="selme">
<option id="a" value="1">I need it</option>
</select>
```

how i can get the value "I need it" whenver it will select.

i not talking about attribute "value" i need a value who fill inside option tags of dropdownlist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$("#selme").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").text();
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdyQn/)

Comment: ack, I was about to write a similar answer, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: too complicated, $('#selme').val(); is pretty enough!

Comment: This won't fetch the correct result in the context mentioned. This will fecth the value and not the text.

Comment: @Andreyco .val() won't get the "I need it" string

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2970457bc8ec7ec5?pli=1

All there for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle for you I just made http://jsfiddle.net/AqmZp/

Basically it actually is just $("#selme").val();

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`$('#selme option:selected').text();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selme option:selected').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check it Out-->**

**For getting text**

```
$("#selme").change(function(){
 $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text();
});
```

**For getting value**

```
$("#selme").change(function(){
 $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
});
```